# How to check if a prop exists and is being passed down

Tags: reactjs

So I have a component like  which contains some data like headerImage = 'image.jpg' description = 'lorem ipsum' ... ,and a builder component that takes these props and builds a page for each brand like this :

```
function IndividualBrand({headerImage,description ....}) {
       return <div>{description}</div>  ...etc
        }
```

How can i conditionally render a prop if it exists in the brand component. Like ,if  contains listDescription , then render {listDescription}

I have this builder component:

```
      function IndividualBrand({
         headerImage,
         description,
         list,
         video,
         homeSite,
         videosArray,
        })
```

and I try to conditionally render something like this :

```
{list !== undefined(
            <div
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "column",
                gap: "1.3rem",
              }}
            >
              <ul style={{ fontSize: "1.3rem", marginLeft: "1.3rem" }}>
                {list}
              </ul>
            </div>
)}
```

but I get an error like undefined is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are missing double *ampersand* (logical AND) when rendering your JSX.

```
{list !== undefined && (
   <div>
     ...
   </div>
)}
```

that can be shortened to:

```
{list && (
   <div>
     ...
   </div>
)}
```

Comment: Thank you,I was missing the && operator,i feel so stupid...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditionaly render in your component:

```
return (<div>
  {!!listDescription && <MyListDescriptionComponent {... props} />}
</div>)
```

If `listDescription` does not exists, is undefined, null, etc... it will not be rendered, if it exists so your component will be rendered as normal.